# csvをheaderとして結合したい

Tags: python, pandas, csv

同じ列数を持つcsvを片方をheaderに設定するように結合したい

やってみたこと

- header.csv

```
Columns: [a,b,c] Index: []
```

- axis.csv

```
Columns: [1,2,3]
　　　　　[4,5,6]
```

```
df=pd.read_csv('header.csv')
df1=pd.read_csv('axis.csv')
df2=pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

理想

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

現実

```
1,2,3,a,b,c
4,5,6
```

Comment: 後で `df` や `df1` を使わないのであれば `df2 = pd.read_csv('axis.csv', names=pd.read_csv('header.csv').columns)` としてもよろしいかと。

Answer (score 0):

片方がヘッダのみならばcolumnsの代入で対応可能です。

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('header.csv', header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('axis.csv', header=None)
df2.columns = df1.columns
print(df2)
```

出力結果:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```